# Export iPhone or iPad Backup to an external hard drive

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, ipad, backup

Is there a way to transport the Data of an iPhone / iPad Backup and the saved apps to an external hard drive?

I'm using iTunes 12.3 on a MacBookProRetina with Yosemite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Apple documents the folder in which iTunes saves backups here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215

Apple doesn't make tools to poke at those files and export the data, however.

The apps themselves are saved in the iTunes library - so you can move them easily. The data embedded in apps depend on how the developer of that app chose to store them. Many use `sqlite` and xml and other standard data formats, so it's not unreasonable to get at many of the files - some are even stored with odd names, but still the correct image and sound and movie file formats.